# Issue with background-image: in css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add an image to the background of my website, and it isn't seeming to work. (Code is lacking because I am trying to get this to work first.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="nav">
        <h4 class="nav-text">USER</h4>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background-color:black;
    background-image: url("background.png")
}

.nav {
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 50%;
    height: 45px;
}

.nav-text {
    opacity: 100%;
    color: white;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-top: 12px;
}
```

What am I supposed to change to make it display the image rather than do nothing?

Comment: Where is `background.png` saved in relation to the CSS file? Maybe the image path isn't correct and that's why no image is shown.

Comment: same folder as where the css and php file is.

Comment: `url("background.png")` means "the `background.png` is in the same folder as this CSS file." If that's not the case, then you need to tell the CSS file where the image is located.

Comment: They are in the same folder, so that shouldnt be the issue?

Comment: Maybe adding the semicolon: ` background-image: url("background.png");`

Comment: it must be an issue with how I am linking the two files, since it isnt seeming to update any changes I make to the css file.

Comment: adding the semicolon didnt make a difference :(

Comment: apparently it was an issue with my browsers cache, im not sure what that means but its fixed now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was an issue with my browsers cache, pressing `CTRL + F5` fixed the issue.